# c# linq join parent and child in generic extension method

Tags: c#, linq

i've got many ef core entities with a possibility to join a shared child table ( without FK-s). I created a generic join extension method, but got a bit stuck returning the main parent entity with the child mapped to it.

Heres what i've got :

```
public interface IBaseEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }
 
public interface IBaseAttachmentEntity:IBaseEntity
    {
         ICollection<ResourceAttachment> ResourceAttachment { get; set; }
    }
public  class ResourceAttachment:BaseEntity
{
    //PK- Id of the parent table
    public long ParentId { get; set; }
    // type or enum of a parent table. Should point to which table it points to
    public string ResourceType { get; set; }
    
    public string AttachmentType { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}


public static class EFCoreExtension
            {
    //this must be a generic method, want to use it for ~30 tables where the entity inherits IBaseAttachmentEntity
                public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeResourceAttachment<TEntity>
                    (this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable,IServiceProvider serviceProvider) where TEntity : class,IBaseAttachmentEntity
                {
                    var className = queryable.ElementType.Name;
                    var attachmentRepository = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IResourceAttachmentRepository>();
                    var attachments = attachmentRepository
                        .FindAllQueriable(x => x.ResourceType == className); //this part is fine 
         
                    var joined = (from q in queryable
                            join a in attachments on q.Id equals a.ParentId into qa
                            from a in qa.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select  new {Parent=q,Attachments = qa}); // joining the child table, ending up with a tuple like result 
        
                    return joined.Select(x => x.Parent); // need to return the Parent together with Parent.ResourceAttachment which id defined in the 
                }          
    
            }
```

want to use the extension like this:

```
   var result =  _deviceServiceService.FindAllQueriable(CurrentUserId(), matchFilter)
                .IncludeResourceAttachment(_serviceProvider).ToList();
```

**EDIT:**

i have also created a minimal sample project to run. Uses In memory Db with data seeding

https://github.com/rauntska/EFGenericChildJoin

Thanks!

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve] (which I could copy and paste to a console app) then it'd be easy to answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity - created one sample project. Link in updated description :)

Comment: @Rnts you don't need such a method in the first place - EF already generates JOINs from the model configuration. If you end up using JOINs in queries, something's wrong. There's no need for base entities either, as EF and LINQ work with plain DTOs. You don't gain anything by creating a base class with an `Id` field, when that field is only used *by convention*. You could add the same field to any class, or use any field you like with the correct attributes, or configure the PK in `OnModelCreating`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Just added the code that i have. Got some extra stuff there that each entity inherits, some base classes ( ie change tracking properties , etc)- using these to determine which classes the entities inherit and do stuff before/after save depending on that.  A bit out of context here and misleading, i agree. That's not the issue here though.

Answer (score 0):

THis might not be what you want, but you might have to settle for it:

```
public static IEnumerable<TEntity> IncludeResourceAttachment<TEntity>
    (this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable, IServiceProvider serviceProvider) where TEntity : class, IBaseAttachmentEntity
{
    var className = queryable.ElementType.Name;
    var dataContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
    var attachments = dataContext.Set<ResourceAttachment>().Where(x => x.ResourceType == className);

    var joined =
        from q in queryable
        join a in attachments on q.Id equals a.ParentId into qa
        select new { Parent = q, Attachments = qa };

    foreach (var x in joined)
        foreach (var y in x.Attachments)
            x.Parent.ResourceAttachment.Add(y);
    
    return joined.Select(x => x.Parent);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is trying to generalise what doesn't need generalising. Adding an `Attachments` property to every class that needs it would be enough, perhaps with a bit of extra configuration in `OnModelCreating`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  -Thanks for the reply.  The thing is that i want to add the ICollection<ResourceAttachment>  to ~30 tables. BUT , i dont not wish the ResourceAttachment to end up with 30 columns for each FK . (CustomerId,ContractId  ..etc) . In plain sql its easy to join tables like that- (without FK-s). Trying to achieve something similar in linq here.

Comment: yup, the downside here is indeed the possibility to end up with ghost records in ResourceAttachement table that dont have a parent anymore. This is though the best idea that i came up to to solve the issue. Though- im open to suggestions if there are some alternatives to achieve the same thing :) ( though the 30 FK-s columns i'd still like to rule out). NB! - i also had an original issue where i was discussing the modelling options- though i did not receive any good feedback there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927759/ef-core-shared-child-table-with-one-to-many